# How can I get the number of comments per page?

Tags: theming, paging

I need the value "default comments per page" for special theming in comments-type.tpl.php for Drupal 6. Should I use `variable_get()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those variables are stored per content type, named `comment_default_per_page_TYPE`. So to get the default comments per page for the `article` content type you would use:

```
$default = 50;
$per_page = variable_get('comment_default_per_page_article', $default);
```

Comment: Where can i found this functions with some examples? I looked at the drupal API but i get not such easy solution. Is there any other varibale for the first and last comment per page?

Comment: `variable_get()` /`variable_set()` use a general storage system for variables, identified by a string (e.g. 'comment_default_per_page_article'). The usage doesn't get any more complicated than the above, but there's no simple way to find every variable name in the system, no. You just need to look through the code to find the ones you're interested in. I wouldn't have thought there's a variable for the first and last comment page - the first page is always 1, and the last page is based on the number of comments which can grow. A static var for that doesn't really make sense

Comment: Ok, thanks again! that makes sense. I mean the first and last comment for one page. Think i can calculate it anyway.